# Efficiently count possible nim-like moves

Tags: combinatorics, induction, combinatorial-game-theory

Consider $n$ piles of coins, with pile $i$ having $a_i$ coins. A valid move is to remove zero or more coins from each of the piles, with the constraint that atleast one pile should remain unchanged, and with the goal that after the move, the XOR sum of all the pile sizes should be $0$.

Given some game configuration (where the XOR sum or nim-sum is not already $0$), how many valid moves are possible, that bring the XOR sum to $0$?

The range of coins in each pile can range up to $10^9$ (30 bit numbers), and there could be around 100 piles, so a brute force is out of the question. The solution needs to be efficient in terms of time complexity.

This was a question I encountered in a programming contest, which is long since over and closed. I was trying to use induction to get a recursive formulation, but could not do so. How can we count the number of moves?

Comment: My phone fails to let me do searches on MSE (and google adds another layer of distance). But I am fairly certain I have seen a (simpler, less general) variant of this question recently on MSE. Last I looked at it then, it remained unsolved, but discussed. Maybe if you (someone) find(s), this would be a first step.

Comment: @gnometorule: Likely you were remembering this problem, [It seems like a nim variant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294745/it-seems-like-a-nim-variant/294749).

Comment: @hardmath: good link, probably better than the one I remembered, but different. The one I had in mind had "XOR" in the title I believe, but no reference to nim I think in question text.

Comment: @gnometorule You probably meant this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293339/finding-all-number-combination-which-xor-results-to-0 . My question is harder in the sense that there must be atleast one unchanged pile.

Comment: @mayank: That's the one. Unfortunately, it apparently went nowhere after I stopped checking up on it. :(

Comment: Just curious, why is this called a game? You are just considering one move to obtain the goal defined by the XOR sum. If there is to be another move after this one, it's not clear what the XOR sum is good for. And in this case the rules prevent the last pile to be emptied.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You are right. The question was slightly differently phrased, and I incorrectly adapted it here. I'll edit the question.

Comment: What properties does the final program need to have? If it simply needs to work correctly, without regards to efficiency or elegance, then you can simply have an $n$-fold loop over all possible removals of coins, and check each one for whether it left a pile unchanged and whether it resulted in an XOR-sum of 0.

Comment: @GregMartin $n$ is a parameter, so we can't have an $n$-fold loop. Also, the solution should be efficient in terms of time, and so a brute force is out of the question (since each pile can have around $10^9$ stones - 30 bit values).

Comment: @mayank: I didn't literally mean a hard-coded $n$-fold loop, but rather a loop with a recursive call insde to the $(n-1)$-instance. But I can imagine that brute force is not practical for your needs.... Is it acceptable to split into $2^n$ subcases?

Comment: @GregMartin $2^n$ cases, where $n$ is the number of piles? If so, that too won't be feasible as $n$ can go upto $100$.

Comment: Even ignoring the "one pile unchanged": suppose the (binary rep'n of # coins in) 0th pile starts with 20 1s, while the jth pile ($1\le j\le20$) has a 1 in the jth (leftmost) bit and 0s elsewhere i the first 20 bits. Then piles 0&1 can both lose the initial 1 or not; but if not, then pile 1 can't switch any of bits 2-20. Then piles 0&2 can both lose the 1 in bit 2 or not; but if not, then pile 2 can't switch any of bits 3-20. Continuing this way, I'm seeing $2^{20}$ states to keep track of. How to get around this problem...?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes. The best I could think of was a branch-and-bound kind of brute-force. Hence the question here. I think a counting by construction will be futile, and there has to be another way to get the count, without actually getting the generating the pile counts. Something using dynamic programming maybe?